# jQuery - type 'home' do something (keyup)

Tags: jquery, bind, keycode, keyup

So when I am on my site and I type 'home' I want to do something. I think this can be done using keyup and possibly bind?

h-72
o-79
m-77
e-69

I have manage to do it but I'm sure there is a better way..

```
if (e.keyCode == 72) {
    $(document).keyup(function (u) {
        if (u.keyCode == 79) {
            $(document).keyup(function (l) {
                if (l.keyCode == 77) {...
```

Comment: create a home button instead ?

Comment: Use a single function and store the keys, the on every key press check if you have "home" stored then do what you want.

Comment: Where do you want to check the keyup, in a textbox ?

Comment: @Sheikh Heera no anywhere in the document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var reading = "";
$(window).keypress(function(e){
    reading += String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    if("home".indexOf(reading) < 0)
        reading = "";
    else if(reading == "home"){
        //DO WHAT YOU WANT
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you heard this. The event.which property normalizes event.keyCode and event.charCode.

Comment: Sheikh method does support earlier versions of IE but the e.which isn't the problem. It just needed to be document.keyup & make it toLowerCase.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is keep a buffer of the last n keys pressed. Then all you have to do is check if the word "home" appears in the string. I'll let you sort out the details but the basic structure shouldn't be too hard.

```
//Example of checking if home is contained within "myString"
myString.indexOf("home") != -1;

var keyBuffer;
$(document).keyup(function(u){

    //Keep a key buffer.
    keyBuffer += u.keyCode;

    //Trim keybuffer so it isn't too long.

    //Check for the presence of any of your keywords such as "home" and respond.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
​$(function(){
    $(document).keyup(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var str=$(e.target).val();
        if(str.toLowerCase()=='home')
        {
            alert("Got home here !");
        }      
    });
});​
```

A fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/efQ5g/2/).

Comment: Sorry I wanted this to work anywhere in a document not just inputs.

Comment: Ha no it doesn't, do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

Bases on the Konami Code implementation on jQuery.com

```
if ( window.addEventListener ) {
 var hkeys = [], hhome = "72,79,77,69";
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
hkeys.push( e.keyCode );

if ( hkeys.toString().indexOf( hhome ) >= 0 )
 alert("Home!!!");
 hkeys = [];
}, true);
}
```